# How to calculate third point on line using atan2?

Tags: actionscript-3, atan2

I'm trying to animate some bitmaps out in relation to a center point. They don't all start at that center point, but I want them to fly out as though a force from that center point slammed into them and pushed them outwards radially, such that they fly completely off the stage.

So: I know the center point, and the x and y position of each bitmap arranged around it. For each one I can draw a line from the center to that x,y point. I should then be able to get the angle formed by that line to the horizontal, and then set a destination point farther out on that line. The bitmap will be tweened out to that point. I believe that that is what Math.atan2 is for.

Here's what I've got as I iterate through the array of bitmaps (i is an object):

```
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(i.bitmap.y - centerY, i.bitmap.x - centerX) * 180 / Math.PI;
var dist:Number = 200;              //arbitrary number, just to test
 destX = centerX  + dist * Math.cos(angle);  //destination x
 destY = centerY  + dist * Math.sin(angle);  //destination y
```

Instead of these things gliding out radially, they're jumping around.

I'm having trouble understanding atan2 and exactly what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks,

David

Comment: Just to add to the answers, if possible, you could make use of the MatrixTransformer helper class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/motion/MatrixTransformer.html for it's rotateAroundExternalPoint() and rotateAroundInternalPoint() methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the *180/PI to keep the angle in radians.

```
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(i.bitmap.y-centerY, i.bitmap.x - centerX);
```

Then change destX and destY to

```
destX = i.bitmap.x  + dist * Math.cos(angle);
destY = i.bitmap.y  + dist * Math.sin(angle);
```

Comment: I don't know if I should add a new question or what, but... as I've worked with this I've realized it's no good to hard-code dist as a negative number. The whole point is that these things should animate out from the center point. If we think of the center point as the origin, then if a bitmap's x is > centerX then it should move right; if < centerX it should move left; if y>centerY it should move down, and if y<centerY it should move up. The 'dist' being added should be determined by which of the four quadrants the target point is in. Isn't that what atan2 is supposed to do? How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same effect without trigonometric functions using just vector operations:

```
var dist:Number = 200;              //arbitrary number, just to test
var dx:Number = i.bitmap.x - centerX;
var dy:Number = i.bitmap.y - centerY;
var length:Number = Math.sqrt( dx*dx + dy*dy );
var normalizeddx:Number = dx / length;
var normalizeddy:Number = dy / length;
 destX = centerX  + dist * normalizeddx;  //destination x
 destY = centerY  + dist * normalizeddy;  //destination y
```

This should be much faster, than using trigonometric functions. I don't know the language specifics of actionscript, so probably this can be optimized more.

Answer (score 0):

atan2 could work in this situation I suppose but I would just use atan:

var angle:Number = Math.atan((i.bitmap.y - centerY) / (i.bitmap.x - centerX));

ADDITION:

Code I just saw on another forum that appears to do what you want (there's only a slight difference from what you wrote in the first place)

```
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(mouseX,mouseY-180)-Math.PI/2;
var xNew:Number = 20*Math.cos(angle);
var yNew:Number = -20*Math.sin(angle);
```

Comment: I think you meant Math.atan(... which I tried, but something is still wrong. They're jiggling around. Also you need Math.atan2 if you want the behavior to be consistent in all four quadrants (negative and positive, x and y).

Comment: Also i think the parameters for atan2 are y,x not x,y

Answer (score 0):

You have to get rid of the *180/Math.PI part. The angle has to be in radians. So the first line would look like
`var angle:Number = Math.atan2(i.bitmap.y - centerY, i.bitmap.x - centerX);`
The rest should be fine.